# what's wrong with my javascript scope

Tags: javascript

pretty simple, how do i make my scope work in this example. the first reference of scope logs to the deck function, but the second one logs to the global window. how do i make the second refer to the deck like i want it to.

thanks!

http://jsbin.com/neqevo/1/edit?js

```
function Deck(){
    this.suits = [ // this is an array now
        {
            'suit': 'diamonds',
            'symbol': '&diamondsuit;',
            'color': 'red'
        }

    ]; // close suits

    this.cardValues = [
        {
            'name': 'ace',
            'face': 'A',
            'value': 1
        }
    ]; // close cardValues

    this.cards = [];

    console.log(this);

    this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit){

        var scope = this;

        console.log(scope);

      // scope doesn't work.
      // obviously, scope references window
      // so how do i get it to refer to the deck like it's supposed to.
      // i looked into using call and apply, and even though the concepts 
      // made sense i couldn't figure it out.
      // fuck this is frustrating!

    });
}
```

Comment: Asked and answered many times here. See suggested duplicate. I suggest you read up on exactly how `this` works and what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either store a reference to `this` in the enclosing function and use that:

```
var me = this;
this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit) {
    console.log(me.suits);
});
```

Or use `bind`:

```
this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit) {
    console.log(this.suits);
}.bind(this));
```

Or use the second argument to `forEach`: (This is probably the best solution.)

```
this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit) {
    console.log(this.suits);
}, this);
```

Comment: damn! i was so close. thanks for your help.

Comment: Or use the second argument to `forEach`: `this.suits.forEach(function()..., this)`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Ah! I didn’t know about that. I’ll edit that in.

Comment: @icktoofay, what makes the third solution the best?

Comment: @heyjohnmurray: It looks the cleanest to me; you can continue using `this` in the inner function, but there’s no overhead from `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

U checked it like that (?):

```
 $this = this;
 this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit){

    var scope = $this;

    console.log(scope);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference variable to the deck scope first...

```
function Deck(){
    var self = this; // save a reference to the deck context

    this.suits = [ // this is an array now
        {
            'suit': 'diamonds',
            'symbol': '&diamondsuit;',
            'color': 'red'
        }

    ]; // close suits

    this.cardValues = [
        {
            'name': 'ace',
            'face': 'A',
            'value': 1
        }
    ]; // close cardValues

    this.cards = [];

    console.log(this);

    this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit){

        var scope = self;

        console.log(scope);

      // scope doesn't work.
      // obviously, scope references window
      // so how do i get it to refer to the deck like it's supposed to.
      // i looked into using call and apply, and even though the concepts 
      // made sense i couldn't figure it out.
      // fuck this is frustrating!

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to pass "this" as a second argument to forEach. So if you edit

```
   this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit){
      var scope = this;
        console.log(scope);
    });
```

to

```
  this.suits.forEach(function(currentSuit){
      var scope = this;
        console.log(scope);
    }, this);
```

then calling new Deck() will console log "Deck" in both cases.